# proving an automaton language for the language over $\{a,b\}^{*}$ : $w\in L$ if $aa$ is not an infix of $w$ ($aa$ doesn't appear in $w$)

Tags: finite-automata

I built the next automaton:
[image]

I have problem to prove $L = L(q_0)\cup L(q_1)$, (when $L(q)$ denotes words $w$ such that $\hat{\delta}(q_0,w) = q$ at a given DFA) because semantically $L(q_0)$ is the language of words over $\{a,b\}^*$ which don't start with $a$, and $L(q_1)$ is the language of words which start with $a$  (by the way, one could also say $L(q_0)$ are the words which don't end in $a$ and $L(q_1)$ are the words which end with $a$).I failed to understand why  $L(q_0)\cup L(q_1) = L$.

My second question, Is it "valid" to prove that $L(q_2) = L^c$, generally speaking, does it valid to prove $\bigcup_{q\in F^c} L(q) = L^c$ in order to prove $L(A)= L$ ? (when $F$ is the set of finite states of an automaton A)

Comment: You should improve your question a bit. First of all in your title you want to "prove an automaton"? You pro want to prove that your automaton is correct for the language $L$. Second, $\in$ or $\notin$ should not be confused with "is an infix of" or "is not an infix of", respectively.
Finally, the notation $L(q)$ seems weird, it was not clear to me if it is the set of words that run on the DFA starting at $q$ or ending in $q$.

Comment: So you want to prove that $L(\mathcal{A}) = \{w \in \{a, b\}^\ast \mid aa \text{ is not an infix of } w\} =: L$. 
You can do this via induction, and you actually have some sort of induction hypothesis stated in your question:
Show that for every word $w \in \{a, b\}^\ast$ with run $(r_0, \ldots, r_n)$ it holds that: $r_n = q_0$ if $w$ does not contain $aa$ and the last symbol was not $a$, $r_n = q_1$ if $w$ does not contain $aa$ and the last symbol was $a$, $r_n = q_2$ if $w$ does contain $aa$.

Comment: As you have stated you can also prove that $L^C$, i.e. the langauage of all words containing $aa$ is actually accepted by the same automaton, just with accepting and non-accepting states flipped, but this does not simplifies the induction above.

Comment: Thanks for edit suggestions, I tried to improve it - I hope now it is clearer. Regarding your answer, as I understand it, an Induction is a syntactic way to prove automaton's language. But I wish to try and prove $L(A) = L$  semantically. So I wish for an explanation (if exists) why $L(q_0) \cup L(q_1)$ is semantically the same as $L$. @PHPNick

Comment: There is an automatic way to prove what you want. Complement your automaton so that it generates $\Sigma^*aa\Sigma^*$, then use known algorithms to show that your automaton indeed generates $\Sigma^*aa\Sigma^*$ (convert the regular expression to an NFA and then to a DFA, compute the symmetric difference DFA, and show that no accepting state is reachable from the initial state using BFS/DFS).

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a "semantic" proof. The semantic proof is to describe the languages of the states, i.e., $L(q_0),L(q_1),L(q_2)$. Then you need to prove that your semantic description is correct, by induction. Compare this to the purely syntactic proof in my preceding comment.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks for explaining the general idea in the first comment, it helps a lot. Regarding my intentions when saying "semantic" proof  -  Let us assume the next question: $L(q_0) , L(q_1)$ as described in the question are given, without any other detail about the automaton, but the fact that $F = \{q_0 , q_1\}$ - could one reconstruct the language $L$? (Generally speaking, is it always possible to reconstruct $L$ only from the semantic representation of $ \{L(q_i) \} _ {q_i \in F}$ ?)

Comment: Certainly – $L = L(q_0) \cup L(q_1)$.